# parameter-aware scoring function on GridSearch sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

Is there a way to pass the current candidate model as an input to a custom scoring function?

I am looking for something similar to the`cross_val_score` method, where `clf` is one of the inputs.

Passing the model as an extra argument does not work since the copy of the candidate is model is not carried in the scoring procedure. What I get instead is an unfitted model with the default parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's how scoring works in `GridSearchCV`: the `scoring` parameter can be a callable, with signature `(estimator, X, y)`.  The search fits a copy of the estimator on training folds, and passes that into your scorer together with the test fold data.  See the [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#implementing-your-own-scoring-object).

Comment: And correct me if I am mistaken: no `make_scorer` around the scoring function is needed  anymore. Passing a simple function with `(estimator, X, y)` is enough?

Comment: @KDaneelOlivaw Right.  `make_scorer` is a convenience function to create this kind of scoring function from a metric function, but you need(/want) the additional flexibility.  Just take care to think about some of the `make_scorer` options: the search will treat larger scores as better (so negate the value if needed), you get to take `predict` or `predict_proba` at your discretion, etc.